# Specify and rename ticks in FrameTicks

Tags: plotting, ticks

When I plot, I use

```
Frame -> True
```

I would like all ticks on the frame axes to disappear and remain only with two ticks, say, 0.1 on the x-axis and 0.5 on the y axis. Also, I would also like to change their labels from the value 0.1 to "x1" and from the value 0.5 to "y1"

Anyone have an idea what to write in

```
FrameTicks -> ?????
```

to get what I describe.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Begin by reviewing the many earlier questions on Ticks.

Comment: The documentation says, "For each edge, tick marks can be specified as described in the notes for `Ticks`."  Expand the "Details" section to get a complete description.

Answer (score 9):

Something like this, maybe?

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, π},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{{{.5, "y1"}}, None}, {{{1., "x1"}}, None}}]
```

[image: plot]

The important thing to keep in mind about specifying frame ticks is that they are given in the order

```
FrameTicks -> {{leftYTicks, rightYTicks}, {bottomXTicks, topXTicks}}
```