# Fitting to the data points are not proper

Tags: plotting

I have a data set, I am trying to join all the data by a line. But I am afraid the plot is not doing it properly.

This is the example (or almost) of my problem:

```
data = {{0, π}, {π/2, π/2}, {π/2, 
    3 π/2}, {π, 0}, {π, 
    2 π}, {3 π/2, π/2}, {3 π/2, 
    3 π/2}, {2 π, π}};
```

Now, trying to interpolate the data.
Result is

[image]

instead of

[image]

Sorry, I just downloaded and directly uploaded (as I couldn't get this result). $x,y$ are from $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Are you just trying to draw a square? Alternatively do you know that your points lie on the boundary of a square and you are trying to find the   boundary? More clarification needed please.

Comment: @Hugh Yes! This is a misleading fig(sorry for that). My points live on the boundary of the square.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[data[[FindShortestTour[data][[2]]]],
 Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[data]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get axis label in terms of pi's? I am not able to get that(for aesthetic)

Comment: See [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75958/specify-and-rename-ticks-in-frameticks).

Answer (score 7):

Your data do lie on the boundary of a square. However their order is not going around the square. Here I plot them and number them.

```
Graphics[{Point[data], 
  Table[Text[ToString[n], data[[n]], {1, 1}], {n, Length@data}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By inspection I can see a better order and then I reorder your data and plot.

```
ord = {1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 7, 5, 3, 1};
data2 = data[[ord]];
Graphics[{Line[data2]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this what you need or are you looking to do this automatically? That would be much more advanced.