# How to set Frameticks properly?

Tags: plotting, ticks, frame

I want to do a MatrixPlot and set the ticks to be from $-1$ to $1$ for both axes. Here in this (post [Specify and rename ticks in FrameTicks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75958/specify-and-rename-ticks-in-frameticks)) it is said FrameTicks work in this way

```
FrameTicks -> {{leftYTicks, rightYTicks}, {bottomXTicks, topXTicks}}
```

But when I try to do it using the following command

```
MatrixPlot[{{1, 0.316287, 0.0926149}, {0.0382826, 0.60648, 
   0.115326}, {0.136868, 0.511539, 0.135918}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{-1, 0, 1}, None}, {{-1, 0, 1}, None}}]
```

I get the plot below. Why it doesn't work properly?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The coordinates 0 and –1 are not visible in the plot because they lie outside the plot. What you want is to set the *labels* –1, 0, 1 at the coordinates 1, 2, 3.

```
ticks = Transpose[{Range[3], Range[-1, 1]}]

(* {{1, -1}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}} *)

MatrixPlot[{{1, 0.316287, 0.0926149}, {0.0382826, 0.60648, 
   0.115326}, {0.136868, 0.511539, 0.135918}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{ticks, None}, {ticks, None}}]
```

[image]